# NullPointerException: Timertask Cancel and Object Disposing

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, try-catch, timertask

This is my first time here. Please, excuse my bad English.

I am writing here to ask a question about `TimerTask` and collateral effects of object disposing.

Here is a simple example. This example shows a `JFrame` with a big button which starts a `TimerTask`. This task only writes a message, sleeps 6 seconds, and writes another message.

Every 10 secs (it's not important this fact) the task is executed.

If I click the button (when I know that the task is stopped and in the sleep method), the object writer (that let's us write a message) is set to null and the timer is cancelled.

Then, if I cancel the task, and an execution of this task is running, it can be thrown `NullPointerException` (remember that writer was set to null).

My question is: how can I avoid `NullPointerException` in this case? Catching it in the 
run method of Timertask? or directly interrupting the task with interrupt method?

Thank you for your understanding.

```
public class CancelTimer extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CancelTimer().setVisible(true);
    }

    Timer timer;

    Writer writer;

    public CancelTimer()  {
        super();

        writer=new Writer();

        timer= new Timer("timer");
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                writer.print("Start and wait");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(6000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    writer.print("Bye, bye!");
                } catch (NullPointerException e){
                    System.out.println("NullPointerException due external disposing task!");
                }
            }
        }, 3000, 10000);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JButton button= new JButton();
        button.setAction(new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                writer=null;
                timer.cancel();

            }
        });
        panel.add(button,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setContentPane(panel);
        this.pack();
        this.setSize(new Dimension(400,400));
    }

    private class Writer {
        public void print(String text){
            System.out.println("PRINT SOME TEXT: "+text);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Did you ever find an elegant solution to this problem? I am experiencing the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set your `writer` to null, but instead use a `boolean` value to track whether or not your task is active, you can save the trouble of having to catch the `NullPointerException`.

Basically, track the state of whether or not you should be writing something some other way. Setting your `writer` to `null` is just silly, because, as you've noticed, it then requires you to catch and handle an exception. This is **not** what exceptions are for.

Comment: I agree with you, but i think my explanation it wasn't clear. Imagine that in the task, you are getting info of another sources or other objects from other classes. If some of these sources is disposed, when you cancel task, you may find a NullPointerException because these resources can be setted to null. Imagine that you are drawing something in a form and the window that contains it, is disposed and setted to null.

Comment: Well, that's a nice theoretical situation, but is that actually happening, or are you talking about something that **might** happen, but in practice doesn't? I can't help you with "imagine that..." if you're not talking about a real problem that actually happens, so we can talk specifics.

Comment: Well, i was thinking more about my question and finally,there is no problem with the TimerTask. If the timertask throw NullPointerException Timer's thread stops and doesn't do anything. Then, there is no problem with previous disposes.
Thank you for you answers normalocity!